# What's the difference between tiger128,3 and tiger128,4?

Tags: php, hash, cryptography

I can not find any documentation about what the 3 or 4 means. What is the difference between these two algorithms?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I was curious to see what, if anything, I could gather from context.  Problem is I cannot find references to tiger128,3 and tiger128,4 so far.  Do you have a link I could check out for curiosity's sake?  I will say my first hunch was relating to digest size, but as the 3 variants are 192, 128, and 160 bits, that doesn't seem to be the right answer.  I am curious about it...

Comment: Oh I just stumbled across what I think is the answer.  That 3 and 4 are the number of rounds used.  Actually that was for a reduced round online variant.  Not sure if it is what you had in mind.

Comment: Already asked and answered [at crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/28986/1172) (disclaimer: by me :P )

Answer (score 2):

This is specific to PHP.

> It is the ***number of passes*** that PHP performs when computing the hash.  The compression function (the compress macro) is set up to perform either 3 or 4 passes, with a key scheduling between each.  The code is slightly tricky because they store the distinction between 3 and 4 passes in 1 bit of the hash context, as the number of additional passes to perform.
>
> **The algorithms ending in ",3" are the *standard* Tiger algorithm;** their output for the empty string matches the empty string's hash in the testtiger code from the Tiger website.  But the output is not in MSB-first order; see the note about Wikipedia below.  (The bug was filed with PHP as #60221; this naturally spawned #61307 when their fix changed the output order in PHP 5.4.0.)
>
> **The algorithms ending in ",4" are *non-standard*,** and should perform 33% slower because there's 33% more work being done.  As I understand it, this extends Tiger to 32 rounds (from 24), which should make it significantly harder to break.  Disclaimer: I'm not a crypto expert, so you should consult with experts if you want accurate, up-to-date information on the security of your specific application.  Ideally, you'd be using a well-vetted library that already made a secure choice.

http://sapphirepaw.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/phps-hash-how-tiger1923-and-tiger1924.html

Comment: Yeah, more or less.  Key in that page was that the " ,3" version is standard and " ,4" is possibly more secure but is slower due to having one more pass.  So pluses and minuses to each variant.

Comment: Don't forget to use @ if you want to reply to somebody specific. I might not have come back and undownvoted your answer.